# Good asp.net (C#) apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, design-patterns

Any suggestions for good open source asp.net (C#) apps out there which meet as many of the following:?

1. Designed well and multi tiered
2. Clean & commented code
3. Good use of several design patterns
4. Web pages display properly in all common browsers
5. Produces valid html and has good use of css
6. Use of css themes. Prefer usage of css than tables
7. NOT dependent on third party components (grids, menus, trees, ...etc)
8. Has good unit tests
9. Web pages are not simplistic and look professional
10. Uses newer technologies like MVC, LINQ.. (not important)
11. (Anything else that matters which I couldn't think of right now)

Comment: I would've answered StackOverflow, but it's not open-source :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have to agree with [BlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/).  It implements a ton of different abilities and common needs in asp.net as well as allowing it to be fully customizable and very easy to understand.  It can work with XML or SQL (your choice) and has a huge community behind it.

As for your requests (**bold** means yes):

1. **Designed well and multi tiered**
2. **Clean & commented code**
3. **Good use of several design patterns**
4. **Web pages display properly in all common browsers**
5. **Produces valid html and has good use of css**
6. **Use of css themes. Prefer usage of css than tables**
7. **NOT dependent on third party components (grids, menus, trees, ...etc)** - *kind of, still uses some custom dlls*
8. Has good unit tests - *not sure*
9. **Web pages are not simplistic and look professional** - *yes, and there are TONS of free templates out there*
10. Uses newer technologies like MVC, LINQ.. (not important) - *not yet*
11. (Anything else that matters which I couldn't think of right now) - *a ton more stuff like dynamic rss feeds, dynamic sitemaps, data references, etc.*

There is also a bunch more great open source projects available here: http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

I know that [dotNetNuke](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/dotnetnuke/) is pretty popular as well, and the [Classified Program](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/classifieds/) is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [SharpArchitecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) which uses ASP.NET MVC, and which is an open source architecture foundation for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

[BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[dasBlog](http://www.codeplex.com/dasBlog) which is a blogging platform that [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) contributes to.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty cool. Upcoming [ASP.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet) feature source is available.

Answer (score 0):

TaskVision: a simple and sometimes very usefull .net client-server demo application:
[Go to website](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/applications/entry1266.aspx)

Complete source code is available (see bottom right corner for download)

Answer (score 0):

Code Plex ->

1. ASP.NET MVC - look at source
2. ASP.NET Dynamic Data
3. Script #

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from SutekiShop (mvc, repository pattern, ddd+tdd), TechAvalanche sample app (http://www.simonsegal.net/blog/CodeDownloads/Orm.zip, several design patterns, poco with linq), CodeBetter.Award sample app for ddd+tdd, and MVC Storefront from Rob Conery.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't met all all points you specified but i'll mention it because i think is a good piece of software http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [MojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com/) (http://www.mojoportal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is MojoPortal (http://www.mojoportal.com/) :

- well designed
- css template & valid html => ok for all browsers
- open source
- perhaps not very modern (no MVC, no LINK...)
- but runs on Mono

For a more up-to-date project, there is Dropthings (http://www.dropthings.com/) : an open source Web 2.0 style AJAX Portal built using ASP.NET 3.5, Workflow Foundation and LINQ.

And its author is considering making an ASP.NET MVC version using jQuery (http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2008/07/15/open-source-asp-net-3-5-ajax-portal-new-and-improved.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OXITE](http://oxite.codeplex.com/) on [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/).