# Asp.net open-source project as a learning source in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-source

I am looking for an open-source asp.net (preferably .net 2.0) project in c#. It doesn't matter if it is some kind of a shop or cms or anything else. What matters is the size of the project that must be at least of medium size (not a simple app that was done in 2 weeks by one developer) and it would be a great advantage if the project contained unit tests and some kind of case study.

I want to use this project as a learning source. I know there are many books and web resources about asp.net but i would like to see how bigger projects are implemented. I am especially interested in implementation of user rights to certain parts of application, separation between html and application logic and i would like to see if developers use .net web controls or write their own custom controls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same question here: [**Good asp.net (C#) apps?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90560/good-asp-net-c-apps)

[BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) was mendtioned twice:

> It implements a ton of different
>   abilities and common needs in asp.net
>   as well as allowing it to be fully
>   customizable and very easy to
>   understand. It can work with XML or
>   SQL (your choice) and has a huge
>   community behind it.

Comment: I was actually about to recommend that as well. I just downloaded it yesterday and was very impressed with the design. +1

Answer (score 1):

[ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) is a nice open source project.

> ScrewTurn Wiki is a fast, powerful and
>   simple ASP.NET wiki engine, installs
>   in minutes and it's available in
>   different packages.

We use it for documentation in our team. There's a lot of different things to learn from the code: theming, compression, how to write an RSS feed, configuration, multi-language support ...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of open source asp.net projects at http://www.codeplex.com or you can also check out any number of the example sites at the ASP.NET homepage at http://www.asp.net